# How can I inject a custom service not associated with any domain class in grails?

Tags: grails, service, dao

I wish to make DAO layer in my grails project which would be not be associated with any of the domain classes and would be interacting with the secondary database of my project. I get the following error when I try to inject the service in any controller:

```
"Cannot invoke method abc() on null object"
```

However, the error is resolved and works perfectly when I initialise the service using the `new` keyword in the controller but I know that shouldn't be necessary as grails is supposed to handle it. Can anyone tell me what am I missing?

Comment: Can you give some more info about how your service is created, how it is injected, and where the method invocation error is coming from?

Comment: Generally a grails service has nothing to do with a domain class. I have written many utility services that interact with 0 domain classes. So long as your service is called SomethingService the key is ending with `Service` and is added to `grails-app/services/{package}/SomethingService.groovy` this is auto injected into your app and you then call  `def somethingService` at top and call somethingSerivce.method() to inject the method. If you create a service in src you can inject such things via `conf/sprint/resources.groovy` but that is off topic from what you asked not clear

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the issue has anything to do with whether or not the service is associated with a domain class.  The DI container doesn't know anything about that.

If you have a controller like this:

```
// grails-app/controllers/demo/SomeController.groovy
package demo

class SomeController {
    SomeService someService

    def someControllerAction() {
        someService.abc()
        // ...
    }
}
```

And a service like this...

```
// grails-app/services/demo/SomeService.groovy
package demo

class SomeService {
    void abc() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

That will work fine.

It is almost impossible to say for sure without seeing what your code what you are doing wrong but one possibility is something like this, which will not work:

```
// grails-app/controllers/demo/SomeController.groovy
package demo

class SomeController {

    def someControllerAction() {
        // This is a local variable, not
        // a property and as such will not
        // be subjected to dependency injection.
        SomeService someService

        // ...
        someService.abc()
        // ...
    }
}
```

Also, make sure the property name (`someService` in the sample above) matches the service class name, but with a lower case first letter (more generally, make sure the property name matches the property name representation of the service class name, which is usually as simple as lower casing the first letter of the class name).